# Segmented Control Shrinks at Runtime after being stretched from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

First time poster here. I've searched all over but I can't find an answer to what it is I'm looking for. If this question has already been asked I'm sincerely sorry, I just couldn't find it.

I am using UINavigationController and would like to use two segmented controls on it, one on the left and one on the right. Each one has 4 or 5 segments with long titles on them. One of the controls has All, Configured, Unconfigured, and Association. Because they're longer words, I'm required to stretch the controls to show all of the text. When I stretch the width of the segmented controls on storyboard it'll look fine however when I run the app they'll shrink right back to the 'First, Second' size. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

I am using Xcode 6 by the way.

Comment: You need to figure out how auto-layout works. You should have warnings or errors in the storyboard that indicate that what you're seeing doesn't match the auto-layout constraints.

Comment: How are you setting the text for your labels?

Comment: @CaptJak there's no label's involved yet. It's just the segment control titles that I'm talking about.

Comment: Well, how are you setting the text? Work with me here.

Comment: @user3386109 I took your advice and looked into auto-layouts, app coda's tutorial if it matters. so far all i've learned is how to make sure everything remains aligned between devices/orientations

Comment: @CaptJak yessir, thank you for your help. I'm a noob so bear with me here.  I've set a segmented control in the upper right hand corner onto the nav control. I click the segmented control and then attribute inspector and where it says 'title' i type in the words you see in the OP. Nothing else. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes, that answers is. Click on the segmented control, go to the editor tab --> Pin --> Width and tell me how that goes.

Comment: @CaptJak all the options are greyed out under pin. I actually tried messing with that from the bottom menu and it wouldn't let me put any values in.

Comment: You can't use auto layout in a navigation bar. Are you saying that the segmented control shrinks so that it's narrower than necessary to display it's text (I don't see that when I try your text)?

Comment: @rdelmar yes precisely. Idk if it has to do with the navigation bar. Because I actually did it without the navigation bar and it was fine, after i found that a navigation bar was required for this project I tried putting the segmented control and faced the issue I posted about.